# Rest Api not returning correct results

Tags: parse-platform

Hi all im having a slight issue with a query im trying to run, i have 2 tables one called common_data that has a couple of fields and a pointer to another class called record now what im looking to do is pull back all the records but ordering them by fields in the common_data class.

So to go about this im actually querying to common_data class and setting the order type and then using include to include the data in the pointer field to the record class. Now every now and then we only want to pull back certain types of records such as images so that is a field in the records class marked as record_type and its value is a number either 1,2 or 3.

so my query looks like this when trying to pull back all images from records using the like_count order as desc in the common_data field

```
{"where":"{"recordid":{"$inQuery":{"where":    {"record_type":1},"className":"record"}}}","order":"-likes_count","limit":500,"skip":0,"count":1,"include":"recordid,recordid.record_parent,recordid.record_common_data"}}
```

now when i pass in the record type here as you can see it wont return certain records that have that type and have a high likes count, for instance if i just remove the record_count and run a query like this

```
{"order":"-likes_count","limit":500,"skip":0,"count":1,"include":"recordid,recordid.record_parent,recordid.record_common_data"}
```

it returns 3 extra records that are not private that have a record_type of 1, now I cant for the life of me figure out why the 3 records appear when i remove the record_type even though the record type of the records is actually 1. Now to make matters worse when someone adds a search term in with those 3 records actually come back.

```
{"where":"{"recordid":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"$or":[{"record_description":{"$regex":"^\\\\Qpo\\\\E","$options":"i"}},{"vehicle_name":{"$regex":"^\\\\Qpo\\\\E","$options":"i"}},{"keywords":{"$all":["po"]}}],"record_type":1},"className":"record"}}}","order":"-likes_count","limit":500,"skip":0,"count":1,"include":"recordid,recordid.record_parent,recordid.record_common_data"}
```

the above query actually pulls them back as it would be expected do. Ive been racking my brain for the last 30 minutes trying to figure out why the first inQuery query isnt returning 3 records that should be whcih match the record_type of one in the record class.

if anyone could help me it would be greatfully appreciated and also is this the best way to query this kind of data structure to get the result im after?

thanks